# Is there a tool that can automatically scale HTML image maps?

Tags: html, image-scaling

We have many imagemaps for a site in early implementation phase.  Unfortunately, a design change requires that we change the physical display size of these maps... are there any tools that can automatically take the <map> data and scale the areas appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, even FrontPage does this- when you downsize the image, it's image map is downsized, too. I believe the "[SharePoint Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BAA3AD86-BFC1-4BD4-9812-D9E710D44F42&displaylang=en)" (available for free) must have the same feature.